# Why does the top fade out earlier than the bottom in this scene?

Tags: transparency

See, in the scene, the top of the flag ends and becomes transparent at a different point then the bottom.  I want the end to be straight, not slanted like I have now.

[image: The scene I was working on (I apologize for the theme)]

Comment: Could you spend a few words about your Texture coordinate node? What's the target object? What are it's rotation values?

Comment: Also why are you multiplying your object coordinates by one? If you want a perfectly horizontal gradient you should be using exclusively the X component of the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting different socket types is generally a bad idea. In this case you have the Object coordinates (a Vector - as indicated by the blue socket) connected to the scalar Value input of a Multiply Math node. This will automatically convert from the vector into a scalar (ie, a plain number) by averaging each of the X,Y,Z values of the vector together - not what you want. Instead, replace the Multiply node with a Separate XYZ node and then use whichever of the X, Y, Z outputs matches your requirements (probably X as indicated in the comments).

Answer (score -1):

Looks as if it might be doing something weird with the color ramp. It's going diagonal instead of left to right.

Edit: You need a gradient texture right after the mapping node to convert to color.